# PLBuildVersion issue in Spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode

I've spent hours trying to solve this problem. After importing ads into my game and was about to update it, I keep getting this message every time I run this.

> objc[14381]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11f958998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11f77a880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

And as a result, I get this kind of issue:
[image: GameOver Scene]

This issue messes up the size and layout of the game. I've tried to google and looking at other answers, but none has ever worked. I've tried importing **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description** **Privacy - Camera Usage Description**, But these have never worked. This may be a bug, but apple still hasn't fixed it in Xcode 8. Someone Please help!

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild?  Also, I doubt the issue is what's causing your messed-up layout; it probably has something else to do with the ads.